# How do I open an external file (epub file) in my Swift App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, epub

I'm trying to make my app available to open external epub files.
When someone wants to open an epub using the Open In menu, I want my app to show up in that menu, and I want to be able to have that epub open in my app.

I've been able to add my app to the Open In menu, but when my app is clicked and opened, there's nothing in the launchOptions parameter, and I don't have access to the epub.

I've added the document types with the following values:

[image]

And I've added an Imported UTI as follows:

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Does anyone have an up to date tutorial that I can view?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  As of iOS 13 with the addition of the SceneDelegate class, you need to retrieve the asset's URL using either the SceneDelegate's...

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)
```

or...

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)
```

...method.  So what I was doing before worked, I just was looking in the wrong place for the asset URL.

I hope this helps anyone who has this problem in the future!